# The servlets named [/HelloServlet] and [com.sample.HelloServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/HelloServlet] which is not permitted

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have made one particular project that having the error:

Problem occured: Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

When I try to start tomcat to run it.
Here's my code. This was taken from the core servlets book.

```
package com.sample;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public HelloServlet() {
super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html"); 
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
String docType = 
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " + 
"Transitional//EN\">\n"; 
out.println(docType + 
"<HTML>\n" + 
"<HEAD><TITLE>Hello</TITLE></HEAD>\n" + 
"<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" + 
"<H1>Hello</H1>\n" + 
"</BODY></HTML>");
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
}
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/i386;;.;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files\broadcom\broadcom 802.11 network adapter\driver;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\tools\binn\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\dts\binn\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\tools\binn\vsshell\common7\ide\;c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\common7\ide\privateassemblies\;c:\program files\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\MinGW\bin;;C:\jee_web_development\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32\eclipse;;.
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:test-app' did not find a matching property.
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloServlet' did not find a matching property.
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 465 ms
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HelloServlet]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HelloServlet]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [/HelloServlet] and [com.sample.HelloServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/HelloServlet] which is not permitted
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2466)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2148)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2109)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1293)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Jan 12, 2014 1:36:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Jan 12, 2014 1:36:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

Jan 12, 2014 1:36:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 12, 2014 1:36:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

I am new to sevlets and have no idea what most of the errors mean. What am I doing wrong? I have search for other questions like this on SO but the answers I found didn't work.

This is my web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sample.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>/HelloServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I actually don't know what this is and what this for. But most project I imported have this So I just make one. Not sure if this is correct though.

Comment: please provide stacktrace

Comment: Please give us the full error in log.

Comment: Question updated with the stacktrace.

Comment: Could you post your web.xml content? As the log says you have a conflict with two servlets using the same url-patter Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [/HelloServlet] and [com.sample.HelloServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/HelloServlet] which is not permitted

Comment: I guess you have mapped your servlet in web.xml also. Please remove web.xml servlet mappings. They will be picked from annotations you have provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be because you're mixing the web.xml servlets configuration with the annotation based configuration, so check that you don't declare the same servlet in the web.xml.

Based in your xml you have two options because you are configuring your servlet with annotations you can delete de tags from your web.xml.
Or if you want to fix your web.xml you need to delete the start / from the servlet-name tag, it need to match with the before servlet name so:

```
<servlet-mapping> 
   <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name> 
   <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This is my web.xml file:
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sample.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>/HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
I actually what this is and what this for. So I just make one. Not sure if this is correct though.

Comment: This is my web.xml file:

<servlet>
<servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sample.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>/HelloServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

I actually don't know what this is and what this for. But most project I imported have this So I just make one. Not sure if this is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import "javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet" to use @WebServlet("/HelloServlet") and you can use portable tomcat and check the port number of tomcat in server.xml file so that tomcat port does not conflict your existing port.

Answer (score -1):

Error: Tomcat Server failed to start

Resolution:

1. Clean the workspace(It works many times
2. Tomcat whle running directly points to the web.xml file..
   Need to check    what is written inweb.xml file....†his also turn out to  be the server issue
3. Sometimes it happens due to improper  binding with jar files.
   For this first add manually jar file in to the WEB-INF ,lib folder and after that 
   Right click on the project and Properties and then add the jar to the build path option.

Properly clean,build the workspace and then again try to start the server.
It will work :)

Answer (score -1):

**Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.**

In my eclipse (Juno) I fixed following ways.

1.Clean project & server

2.Remove **.snap** file from following directory

{workspace-directory}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources

OR

3.Remove **temp** file from following directory

{workspace-directory}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core